# Pandas df to csv inserts blank lines

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have a pandas data frame 'data' that I want to export to csv. It works fine, but some lines are completely messed up. 
I use: data.to_csv('data.csv')

I tried altering the encoding and dropping index, but it didn't work. The first picture are the correct rows, and the second one the rows that got messed up. 
When looking at the messed up rows i figured the problem might be that the text data uses the delimiter \r to separate lines and is exported incorrectly. How can I fix this?

[image: what it looks like for correct rows]

[image: what the incorrect rows look like]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have columns there with embedded new lines/lots of trailing new lines? You might just have to replace/strip them depending if you want to preserve new lines or not... (Or set those columns to be merged and wrap in your spreadsheet program so it looks less horrible)

Comment: Hi Jon, yes, some of the tweets have new lines in them I think. What do you mean by replacing? Already deleting all line breaks in the pd data frame? The problem is not that it looks horrible, but that the columns are totally displaced. I have the tweet instead of the screen_name etc.

Comment: Um... well... embedded new lines as long as they're escaped in quotes should be fine for CSV... depending on how you opened it in your spreadsheet and chose how to treat delimiters - it might be deciding to shift columns and your CSV file is  technically correct. Either export directly to Excel if possible or remove new lines from columns before exporting so your spreadsheet doesn't get a chance to misread it as a start to new rows...

Comment: how can i remove new lines from columns before exporting my spreadsheet? In my data frame everything is correct

Comment: I figured out what delimiter causes the problem: \r. How can i fix it?

Comment: Try updating the tweet column something like: `df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace('\n', ' ')` or whatever's suitable to tweak the column...?

Comment: This worked, thank you. I had hoped to find a way without changing my original data.

Comment: Export directly to spreadsheet format instead of CSV - did you try that?

Comment: Works fine - just takes a while longer. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Just change the line terminator:

```py
data.to_csv('data.csv',line_terminator = '\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that came here because of looping `df.to_csv` inside context manager, use `lineterminator` to fix it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


with open('report_.csv', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(4):  # loop here
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,4)))

        df.to_csv(f,
                  index=True,  # to include index
                  header=True,  # to include header
                  lineterminator='\n',  # to remove whitespace between row
                 )
        f.write('\n')  # remove this to delete whitespace between DataFrame
```

From my original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77535876/11671779)

Answer (score -1):

Change the separator to `\t` or `|` or something other than `,`. You have commas in your strings, which are messing up your comma separation.

Note that your csv's are nothing but text files separating elements using commas. If you have commas in uneven places, it's gonna make extra separation and hence, going to mess up your file.