# Using Pandas to write file creates blank lines

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the pandas library to write the contents of a mysql database to a csv file.

But when I write the CSV, every other line is blank:

[image: blank lines in csv]

Also, it's printing line numbers to the left that I do not want. The first column should be 'Account Number'.

Here is my code:

```
destination = 'output_file.txt'
read_sql = """ SELECT LinkedAccountId,ProductName,ItemDescription,ResourceId,UnBlendedCost,UnBlendedRate,Name,Owner,Engagement FROM billing_info ;"""
fieldnames = ['Account Number', 'Product Name', 'Item Description', 'Resource ID', 'UnBlended Cost', 'UnBlended Rate', 'Name', 'Owner', 'Engagement']
# Open the file
f = open(destination, 'w')
cursor.execute(read_sql)
while True:
    # Read the data
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))
    # We are done if there are no data
    if len(df) == 0:
        break
    # Let's write to the file
    else:
        df.to_csv(f, header=fieldnames)
```

Why is it printing blank lines between the lines with data? How can I get it to create the file without blank lines and without the line number column to the left?

Comment: try `index=False` to exclude the row identifiers.

Comment: What operating system are you running in?  Pandas to_csv() in MS Windows seems to set EOL as \r\r\n giving extra blank rows

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have a look at the official documentation for [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

For convenience, I have posted some items of interest here:

> **lineterminator** : string, optional
>
> The newline character or character sequence to use in the output file. Defaults to os.linesep, which depends on the OS in which this method is called (’\n’ for linux, ‘\r\n’ for Windows, i.e.).
> ⚠️ In older version of pandas, this parameter is called `line_terminator`.

> **index** : bool, default `True`
>
> Write row names (index).

Are probably what you're looking for. As for the empty lines, try explicitly specifying a single newline:

```py
df.to_csv(f, header=fieldnames, index=False, lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Isn't this going to wewrite the headers every 1000 rows? You probably want to set `header` to false after the first iteration.

Comment: @Dan, Ah correct, I was just copying his call for that bit. Since that isn't in his question, I will probably leave as-is

Comment: Thank you! I have partial progress to report. The column showing line numbers at the left are gone! However there are still blank lines in between the lines of data! Any other ideas?

Comment: oh good point about the headers! I'll leave them out of this line. Thanks!

Comment: @bluethundr Try setting line_terminator to something like a semicolon, or maybe even set it to a blank string, otherwise, I'm not sure why there are extra lines. Try opening the CSV file with a plain text editor to see if there are actually extra lines or if it's just the program you are using to view the file

Comment: Thanks @AlgoRythm. But this line you posted the other day worked for me: `df.to_csv(f, header=fieldnames, index=False, line_terminator='\n'). `There are no blank lines between the lines of data anymore. Sorry if I didn't get back to you about that, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Adjusting pandas new line terminator is not the right way to achieve what OP wants. Better to open the file in binary mode and write the string pandas gives you as bytes. See my answer for more info

Answer (score 3):

I came here just for the title and not removal of index numbers. That is why, for completeness sake, I want to add to the accepted answer, that removing the double linebreaks is done just by `line_terminator='\n'`.

In this example this would be

```
f = open(destination, 'w')
df.to_csv(f, line_terminator='\n')
f.close()
```

or when using 'with open(..)'

```
with open(destination, 'w') as f
    f.write(df.to_csv(line_terminator='\n'))
```

Other options such as headers can be added to `df.to_csv()` as needed.

Comment: See my answer why this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

## Open File In Binary Mode

The real problem appears to be double handling of line endings - by python and then again by pandas. While the suggestion to set pandas to use `\n` "works" (displays as you might expect) with python's `open` in **text** mode, this is only by luck and is platform and python version dependant.

**So the short answer is**: Open the python file handle in binary mode with `open(fname, 'wb')` and leave pandas on default behaviour.

```
with open(destination, 'wb') as f:
  df.to_csv(f)
  # also ok...
  # f.write(df.to_csv().encode("utf-8"))
```

This will result in correct line endings per platform, and more importantly, **unchanged CSV values** (Python2 and Python3).

If you **really** want to control line endings, then do this via the pandas API or your CSV could be mangled by Python EOL handling.

---

## In more detail, for those who are interested...

### Beware Unconventional Line Endings

Making your CSV file always use `\n` as new line (via pandas) will produce unconventional line endings depending on the platform.

With the file opened in binary mode (`wb`), or in text mode without universal EOL support - (`w`) in Python2, or (`w, newline=''`) in Python3 - then while the CSV will not be mangled, the file will have unexpected line endings on Windows and Macintosh. This can result in display issues (eg, historically Microsoft Notepad) but otherwise seems to be displayed correctly universally in my experience.

### Mangled CSV Values

With the file opened in text mode **with** universal EOL support (`w`) in Python3, or `wU` in Python2, and pandas configured to use `\n` as new line, then the file will have conventional line endings on all platforms because Python will convert the pandas `\n` to the platform dependant EOL. **However**, any CSV values containing `\n` will be mangled on non Linux platforms, but will likely **look** the same (but may also suffer the extra blank line display issue).

Example of such a CSV:

```
a, b, c
value1, "value
2", value3
```

### What About Consistent Line Endings

There is also a legitimate use case to keep line endings consistent.

One example is to preserve the file hash for CSV across all systems. If you do **really** want consistent line endings regardless of platform, I would choose Windows line endings (`\r\n`) as these will display correctly on Linux and Macintosh too (I think).

Definitely still open the file in binary mode, but supply the desired line ending to pandas. This will guarantee that your CSV **is** identical across all systems (even if it **looks** different when displayed).

### Pitfalls With File Opened In Text Mode

Setting pandas to use `\n` is just leaving you at the mercy of python's line ending handling. It could also be confusing and/or misleading to the reader of code: When a file opened in Python's **text mode** with universal EOL support, the line endings of the CSV will still be `\r\n` on Windows and `\r` on Macintosh, **even with pandas using `\n` as new line**.

Even worse, any `\n` in your CSV values will be mangled by Python on Windows and Macintosh.

### Binary Files Are Best When Using File Handles

The general solution is to **always** open files in binary mode when passing the file handle around.

### When To Use Text Mode

The **only** legitimate use cases for python's text mode is for **writing** strings directly to the file or iterating a file line-by-line that you **know** contains **only** text **where EOL characters never have any other meaning** (which rules out CSV files where any quoted value - including EOL - should be preserved when reading or writing).

---

### Reference Table Of Explicit Examples

| Platform | Python | open mode | pandas EOL | Result | CSV quoted `\n` value mangled | Conventional | Display on Platform |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | 3 | `w` | default | `\r\r\n` | **yes** | **no** | Extra new line between each row |
| Windows | 3 | `w, newline=''` | default | `\r\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 3 | `w` | `\n` | `\r\n` | **yes** | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 3 | `w, newline=''` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | All on one line (notepad) or each row on new line (other editors) |
| Windows | 3 | `wb` | default | `\r\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 3 | `wb` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | All on one line (notepad) or each row on new line (other editors) |
| Macintosh | 3 | `w` | default | `\r` | **yes** | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 3 | `w, newline=''` | default | `\r` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 3 | `w` | `\n` | `\r` | **yes** | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 3 | `w, newline=''` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | ? |
| Macintosh | 3 | `wb` | default | `\r` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 3 | `wb` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | ? |
| Linux | 3 | `w` | default | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 3 | `w, newline=''` | default | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 3 | `w` | `\n` | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 3 | `w, newline=''` | `\n` | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 3 | `wb` | default | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 3 | `wb` | `\n` | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 2 | `w` | default | `\r\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 2 | `wU` | default | `\r\r\n` | **yes** | **no** | Extra new line between each row |
| Windows | 2 | `w` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | All on one line (notepad) or each row on new line (other editors) |
| Windows | 2 | `wU` | `\n` | `\r\n` | **yes** | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 2 | `wb` | default | `\r\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Windows | 2 | `wb` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | All on one line (notepad) or each row on new line (other editors) |
| Macintosh | 2 | `w` | default | `\r` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 2 | `wU` | default | `\r` | **yes** | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 2 | `w` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | ? |
| Macintosh | 2 | `wU` | `\n` | `\r` | **yes** | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 2 | `wb` | default | `\r` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Macintosh | 2 | `wb` | `\n` | `\n` | no | **no** | ? |
| Linux | 2 | `w` | default | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 2 | `wU` | default | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 2 | `w` | `\n` | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 2 | `wU` | `\n` | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 2 | `w` | default | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |
| Linux | 2 | `w` | `\n` | `\n` | no | yes | Each row on new line |

NOTE: even though on Linux the difference between text mode and binary mode has no impact when writing CSV with pandas, it's good practice to open files in binary mode in any case as text mode **will** alter new lines of input text when **reading** files originating on other platforms such as Windows or Macintosh.

Comment: Why open the file manually using "with" or "open"? I've always just used the to_csv method on its own and never had any issues. The original post doesn't have the full dataframe to write all at once, but if you do is there a reason to open the file manually?

Comment: it depends on what df.to_csv('path/to/file') does. It appears to call open with mode 'w' by default. This will cause double handling of line endings on windows and potentially break CSV with '\n' in a cell. Apparently, binary mode ('wb') is not supported, as that would require an encoding to be set, but specifying encoding when given anything other than a binary buffer as the "file" is not allowed: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
Opening the file in binary mode with correct encoding, and specifying lineterminator ensures you get what you expect

Answer (score -1):

To also write whitespace between `DataFrame`,

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


with open('report_.csv', 'w') as f:
    for _ in range(4):  # loop here
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,4)))

        df.to_csv(f,
                  index=True,  # to include index
                  header=True,  # to include header
                  lineterminator='\n',  # to remove whitespace between row
                 )
        f.write('\n')  # remove this to delete whitespace between DataFrame
```

Comment: Doesn't answer OP question